Why doesn't Ctrl-S seem to do anything in the default Mac terminal?
Ctrl-S is supposed to be the STOP part of the START/STOP output control that you can set up with stty. But when I press it, it seems to do nothing. The output doesn't stop and I can still type characters as usual.
stop is set to ^S and ixon is enabled. Why isn't it working?

Apparently the reason is that ixany is enabled in the stty settings.
This means that typing any character after pressing Ctrl-S to stop the output immediately restarts the output again. Disabling ixany fixes the issue.
